# How to secure a RESTful API in Spring Boot without mantain a jsessionid

Tags: spring, api, rest, spring-boot, restful-authentication

I need to create a SpringBoot RESTful API to be consumed either by a web project or a mobile app.

My question is how to secure it without the typically basic authorization that returns you a "jsessionid" to the web browser and mantains the session with it. It's not a problem for the web project, because it could store that jsessionid. But how about to secure the mobile app request to the API?

Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Json Web Tokens?

Comment: Are you asking how to disable jsessionid, or what you should be replacing it with? The latter question is probably off-topic.

Comment: My question was about how to "mantain a session" but no with "jsessionid".. I think that creating an authorization token as another told in another answer would be the solution. THanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the [architectural constraints  of REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) is that it must be stateless.

Your REST API must not have sessions that authenticate the client. Instead, the client should pass some sort of token, commonly placed in the `Authentication` HTTP Header.

[JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) and [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) are both very popular ways of doing this, and you can absolutely use HTTP Basic Authentication with OAuth 2.0 if you wish.

Here's an article called [Stateless Authenticaiton with Spring Security and JWT](http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt). Hopefully that will help!

Comment: I think that this is what I am looking for.. Kind of a token that emulates the sessionid so I don't have to send username & password all over the requests.. I'll have a look at this! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use basic authentication. It work sending username and password on each request but don't need save the sessionid in the client.

Here are a sample application with basic authentication:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication

If you don't save anything in the server session you don't need save the jsessionid in the client.

Comment: So I don't want to send the username & password all over the request.. I just want to login once, and then without "session" (as the achitectural contrsaints of REST say that the API must be stateless session), knowing which user is sending the request, and go through all the spring security chain (like PreAuthorize annotations for example)